# Jqgrid Pagination not working due to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, jqgrid

I am trying to set up a jqgrid and I am having difficulty in constructing the controller that generates the json data to populate the grid. I am using codeigniter 2.0+ and I am not sure how to build the query for php in codeigniter.

I followed [this guid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under "Loading Data -> JSON Data" for the jqgrid. I also consulted [codeigniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) on data selection. The thing is I am not sure how to write the second query to sort and limit according to the jqgrid paramiters. Here is my controller.

```
public function applicantdata(){
    $page = $this->input->get('page');// get the requested page
    $limit = $this->input->get('rows');// get how many rows we want to have into the grid
    $sidx = $this->input->get('sidx');// get index row - i.e. user click to sort
    $sord = $this->input->get('sord');// get the direction
    if(!$sidx){ $sidx =1; }

     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('applicant');
     $this->db->join('transaction', 'transaction.applicant_id = applicant.id');
     $query = $this->db->get();    

     $count = $query->num_rows();
     $limit = 10;         
        if( $count > 0 ) {
            $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
        } else {
            $total_pages = 0;
        }        
        if ($page > $total_pages){ $page=$total_pages; }        
        $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)

//NOT SURE HOW TO DO THIS IN CODEIGNITER ENVIRONMENT
//$SQL = "SELECT a.id, a.invdate, b.name, a.amount,a.tax,a.total,a.note FROM invheader a, clients b WHERE a.client_id=b.client_id ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
//$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());   


        $result = $query->result_array(); 

        $responce->page = $page;
        $responce->total = $total_pages;
        $responce->records = $count;
        $i=0;            
        foreach ($result as $myrow){
            $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$myrow['id'];
            $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($myrow['id'],$myrow['firstname'],$myrow['lastname'],$myrow['amount'],$myrow['status']);
            $i++;
         }       
    echo json_encode($responce);
}
```

With the above code, the grid is populating and its is working to a greater extent. Only thing is the pagination stuff not working properly in that the data on page one shows when I move to page 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Her is the final working thing. For anyone who may need it.

```
public function applicantdata(){
    $page = $this->input->get('page');// get the requested page
    $limit = $this->input->get('rows');// get how many rows we want to have into the grid
    $sidx = $this->input->get('sidx');// get index row - i.e. user click to sort
    $sord = $this->input->get('sord');// get the direction
    if(!$sidx){ $sidx =1; }

     $this->db->select('firstname');
     $this->db->from('applicant');
     $this->db->join('transaction', 'transaction.applicant_id = applicant.id');
     $query = $this->db->get();    

     $count = $query->num_rows();

        if( $count > 0 ) {
            $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
        } else {
            $total_pages = 0;
        }        
        if ($page > $total_pages){ $page=$total_pages; }        
        $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)


        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('applicant');
        $this->db->join('transaction', 'transaction.applicant_id = applicant.id');
        $this->db->order_by("applicant.id", $sord);
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query2 = $this->db->get();               
        $result = $query2->result_array(); 

        $responce->page = $page;
        $responce->total = $total_pages;
        $responce->records = $count;
        $i=0;            
        foreach ($result as $myrow){
            $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$myrow['id'];
            $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($myrow['id'],$myrow['firstname'],$myrow['lastname'],$myrow['amount'],$myrow['status']);
            $i++;
         }       
    echo json_encode($responce);
}
```